# bash script for finding missing files which have variable gaps

Tags: bash, scripts

I have folders with several PNG files like

```
pic_191120081.png
pic_191120241.png
.
.
.
pic_192722801.png
pic_192722961.png
```

so when c5-c8 remain the same, c9-c12 increase of 16. But after a number of files also c5-c8 change.

Is it possible to create a script checking for missing files? For example, after
pic_192722961.png I should have
pic_192723121.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the numbers in the filename are incremented by 160, so, rather than manipulate columns (assuming "c5-8" refers to column numbers) process the whole number.

```
first=191120081
last=192722961
  
num=$first
while [[ $num -le $last ]] ; do
    fnam="pic_${num}.png"
    if [[ ! -f "$fnam" ]] ; then
       echo "Missing $fnam"
    fi
    num=$(( $num + 160 ))
done
```

Comment: it would work if colums 9 to 12 would remain the same, unfortunately it is not the case. After a number of files incrementing of 160 in c5-8, there is another group with increment of 16 but different number looking at c9-12.

Comment: My example above wasn't the best, it could be that c9-12 don't show any logic increment. Instead of pic_1911.... could be pic_2230...